# What's the longest direct route with Flixbus?

Tags: buses, factoids, routes, flixbus

I wonder what the longest direct route with Flixbus is?

As one can get 5 tickets for 20€ each I want to know which route will give the most value to the tickets.

The longest I've travelled on yet with Flixbus was Berlin-Stockholm and that was about 19 hours.

Comment: Distance-wise or time-wise?

Comment: time-wise its Bucharest- Barcelona: 50:15 hours.

Comment: @zhantongz any-wise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Barcelone-Bucharest is 2700+km and takes between 48 and 51 hours on schedule.

If counting by linear distance between cities, London-Bucharest is 2090 km (the bus takes about 46 hours if on schedule) while Barcelona-Bucharest is 1970 km.